# R how to use geom_smooth with transformed Y axis and outside data set?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do you use geom_smooth() using a formula with the following form:

```
log(Unit.Sales_1) ~ log(Price) + A
```

On top of a ggplot that is using a completely different dataset?

I'm currently able to use a transformed axis, a different dataset, but not both at the same time. I get the following error message:

> Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`: object 'Unit.Sales_1' not found

And the rest of my ggplot looks like this:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = hist_data1, aes(x = Price, y = Unit.Sales, color = "Historicals")) +
  geom_line(data = est_data1, aes(x = P1, y = Q1, color = "Estimated")) +
  geom_smooth(data = wide_oj_data,
              formula = Unit.Sales_1 ~ log(Price_1) + log(Price_3) + Promotion_1 + Holiday,
              method = "glm",
              method.args = list(family = gaussian(link = 'log')),
              aes(x = Price_1, y = Unit.Sales_1)
              )
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Please demonstrate that `wide_oj_data` contains column `Unit.Sales_1`.

Comment: Demonstration: It does